# Package for typesetting the Bible

Tags: packages

Are there any LaTeX packages or styles that have been designed specifically for typesetting the Bible, with its text divided into books, chapters, and verses?

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129843/trouble-with-bible-style-page-header-lines) contains a couple of nice pictures of pages from the Bible, but I wonder if there is a proper package for that kind of typesetting.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/vermiculus/bible, never used, just guessing from the name

Comment: Reading the package, it's not a package per se, but a class and template for a specific bible, written by the author. You could use the bible.cls or the relevant files for your own version, but it seems that the more straightforward approach is to write your own style. Other packages, like `bibleref` are just for quotes, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: This might get you started: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262970/2693

Answer (score 4):

Since 2017-09-01 exist also a direct package named done `bibletext` by Camil Staps,

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/bibletext/bibletext.pdf

or `bibleref.sty (1.24)` - 2019/12/10 Nicola Talbot and Maïeul Rouquette - of 6 days ago: 
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/bibleref/bibleref.pdf

where I think, with the comments of several links, to create some steps of the Bible. I suggest also this link [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends)

Answer (score 3):

I've released the [`scripture`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scripture) package which could help for typesetting Bibles.

It's mainly written for producing quotations, but could be used as a basis for typesetting a whole Bible.

The package provides many features commonly seen in Bibles such as dropped text for chapter numbers, superscripts for verse numbers, indented lines for poetry sections, narrow sections and hanging paragraphs.

A simple section of the Bible can be produced as follows:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,b5paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{scripture}
\scripturesetup{
  font=\small,
  version=NIVUK
}
\begin{document}
\begin{scripture}[Isaiah 56:1--2]
  \ch{56}This is what the \textsc{Lord} says:

  \begin{poetry}
    ‘Maintain justice
    and do what is right,

    for my salvation is close at hand
    and my righteousness will soon be revealed.

    \vs{2}Blessed is the one who does this---
    the person who holds it fast,

    who keeps the Sabbath without desecrating it,
    and keeps their hands from doing any evil.’
  \end{poetry}
\end{scripture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Very interesting, David. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with PTXprint?

https://software.sil.org/ptxprint/

It uses XeTeX to publish Bibles and it is open-source. It's also quite possible that it already does what you need off-the-shelf.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Please, can you put an example to see how is it works? +1

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan; I'll take a look at it.